# Absolute Spring resource reference from a jsp page

Tags: spring, jsp, resources

I would like to know how to reference a spring resource from a JSP page without either a relative reference, such as ../.., or some cluge to get the context root.

I have this defined:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/r/**" location="/resources/" />
```

In my jsp I would like something like `<img src="r/images/image.jpg"/>` or

```
<img src="/r/images/image.jpg"/>
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

```
<spring:url value="/r/images/image.jpg" var="imageUrl" htmlEncoding="true"/>
<img src="${imageUrl}"/>
```

Note that [spring:url](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/UrlTag.html) is from the [Spring Tag Library](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html)

Comment: Thank you. This is useful. What would you recommend for a large web page with a LOT of different images, javascript, css, etc. I'm just trying to avoid a lot of complicates JSP scriptlet code and maybe one reference ID or something.

Comment: @user3594045 I can't really think of anything in JSP that would help you manage the resources.